# How can I modify the tool chain to support multiplier only on RISCV

Tags: gcc, llvm, riscv

I have a RTL to support multiplier instruction with RV32I but I have a problem modifying the tool chain to support Multiplier only ISA.  I am trying to modify the M extension by removing the div and rem, but I am not sure which file(s) I should look for.

Comment: Ask on `gcc@gcc.gnu.org`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend instead that a better strategy is to leave DIV/REM unimplemented, and throw an illegal instruction exception when they are encountered.  Then, the machine mode (kernel) can execute the instructions in software.

Even if you're running your code bare metal, it's fairly straightforward to implement machine-mode/user-mode, and provide a SW routine to handle DIV/REM yourself.